# .exe file won't run in VSCode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

I compiled a very simple C program into .exe file. When I try to run it from Windows Command Prompt by typing simply: `program.exe`, it works. That is when I am in a correct directory. However, typing that same `program.exe` command in VSCode doesn't work. It doesn't require administrative privileges to run, and I am also in a correct folder, but I get the following error:

```
program.exe : The term 'program.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ program.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (program.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am new to C and compiling and haven't used VSCode in years so I have no idea what might be the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, VSCode terminal on Windows uses PowerShell, not classic Command Prompt.

In PowerShell, to execute an executable in the current directory, you need to tell PowerShell that it is in the current directory by prepending `.\`, like this: `.\program.exe`

Answer (score 1):

instead of running .\ to execute the file on Windows VSCode, I used ./ and the code executed nicely.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).